# Failed to require a package using Composer

Tags: git, github, composer-php, yii2

I would like to require this package in my project:
[lucianocosta/jquery.mtz.monthpicker](https://github.com/lucianocosta/jquery.mtz.monthpicker)

So I added it in my **composer.json** file:

```
{
      "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
      "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Application Template",
      "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "application template"],
      "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
      "type": "project",
      "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
      "support": {
                "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
                "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
                "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
                "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
                "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
      },
      "minimum-stability": "stable",
      "require": {
                "php": ">=5.4.0",
                "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
                "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
                "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
                "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
                "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*",
                "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta",
                "asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client": "2.2.*",
                "phpoffice/phpexcel": "*",
                "lucianocosta/jquery.mtz.monthpicker": "dev-master"
      },
      "require-dev": {
                "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
                "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*"
      },
      "config": {
                "process-timeout": 1800
      },
      "extra": {
                "asset-installer-paths": {
                          "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
                          "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
                }
      }
```

}

Then I run the `composer update` command but I got this message:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - The requested package **lucianocosta/jquery.mtz.monthpicker** could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:

- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting

Without altering any minimum-stability setting, is this possible that I can require this package successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package which you require is not Composer package because Composer is PHP package manager and package which you want to use is just for frontend.

Frontend packages are mantained with Bower but Yii suggests you to [install `composer-assets-plugin` which can handle Bower packages through `composer.json`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#installing-via-composer) and then you don't need to maintain them in separate [`bower.json`](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#bowerjson).

Then you need to find correct Bower package name. You can do it through website `http://bower.io/search/?q=monthpicker` or if you have Bower installed you can search for this package from command line like this:

```
bower search jquery.mtz.monthpicker

Search results:
    monthpicker git://github.com/lucianocosta/jquery.mtz.monthpicker.git
```

When you have your package name (in this case `monthpicker`), you just need to add it in `require` section of your `composer.json` prefixed with `bower-asset/` (in this case `bower-asset/monthpicker`.

Here is a fixed version of your `require` section:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*",
    "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta",
    "asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client": "2.2.*",
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "*",
    "bower-asset/monthpicker": "dev-master"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the requested package is not a composer package (it has no `composer.json`) and it is not available via the [packagist.org](http://packagist.org) repository. That means that the author of this package didn't provide support for composer.

> A repository is a package source. It's a list of packages/versions. Composer will look in all your repositories to find the packages your project requires.
>
> By default only the Packagist repository is registered in Composer. You can add more repositories to your project by declaring them in composer.json.

But it is possible to register new repositories in your `composer.json`. The following code registers a repository for `lucianocosta/jquery.mtz.monthpicker` and makes use of the [`RobLoach/component-installer`](https://github.com/RobLoach/component-installer) to bring them out of the `/vendor` folder. If you don't need this just remove the `extra` and the `require` section within the `package` section.

```
"repositories": [
     {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "lucianocosta/jquery.mtz.monthpicker",
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "component",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/lucianocosta/jquery.mtz.monthpicker/archive/master.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            },
            "extra": {
                "component": {
                    "scripts": [
                        "jquery.mtz.monthpicker.js"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "require": {
                "robloach/component-installer": "*"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "lucianocosta/jquery.mtz.monthpicker": "1.*"
},
```